# PHP insensitive replace

Tags: php, case-insensitive, str-replace

I am trying to insensitive replace string, so I'm using str_ireplace() but it does something I dont want and I have no clue how to overcome this problem.

so this is my code:

```
$q = "pArty";
$str = "PARty all day long";
echo str_ireplace($q,'<b>' . $q . '</b>',$str);
```

The output will be like that: `"<b>pArty</b> all day long"`.
The output looks like that because I replace insenitive variable `$q` with its sensitive.

How can I overcome this so the output will be `"<b>PARty</b> all day long"`?

Comment: did you read you're question ? `$str = "<b>PARty all day long</b>";` so why would you need str_ireplace ?? i suppose you forgot to mention smth or please edit you're question couse it doens't make any sence to use str_ireplace giving the output you whant !

Comment: I only edited your question for formatting, but for future reference, you can see the edit history by clicking the `edited [some time] ago` link at the bottom of the question. It works like a wiki.

Comment: @poelince, yes I had typo. I meant to write `$str = "<b>PARty</b> all day long"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with `preg_replace`, e.g.:

```
$q = preg_quote($q, '/'); // in case it has characters of significance to PCRE
echo preg_replace('/' . $q . '/i', '<b>$0</b>', $str);
```

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are asking to replace " P A R t y" with  "p A r t y". 
As commanded, php obeyed.
However, why do you even want to replace anything? The original is the word you require.

Comment: I got autocomplete plugin so I wanted to bold the querystring in the results. I am using "like" condition so it return insensitive results, therefore I need to insensitive replace.